# Как максимальную ширину изображения ограничить реальной шириной изображения?

Tags: css

На странице вставлена картинка:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="photo">

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Максимальная ширина картинки - 500px. Если у нас ширина родителя меньше 500px, то картинка занимает 100% ширины родителя.

Но может быть так, что реальная ширина картинки меньше, чем 500px.

Как ограничить максимальную ширину картинки, если она больше 500px, и не растягивать картинку до 500px, если картинка меньшей ширины?

Comment: Уберите `width`, оставьте только `max-width`

Comment: Если убрать width, то при уменьшении ширины родителя не будет уменьшаться ширина картинки. Ширина картинки будет фиксированной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо ограничивать наоборот: сколько надо, но не больше 100%:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_20254e252d91_128.png" alt="photo">
<img src="http://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201411/26/1334081/57542_trava_priroda_doroga_leto_1920x1200_wwwgdefonru.jpg" alt="photo">
```

Comment: Все работает именно так, как нужно, только не могу понять, почему :-) Разве 100% в вашем случае - это не вся ширина родительского блока?

Comment: Вся, но указана только максимальная ширина, т.е. дословно: `не шире родительского блока`.

Answer (score 3):

Сдается мне, что без JS тут не обойтись, а если это окажется так, то вот решение с ним.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.parent img').forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.width >= 500) item.style.maxWidth = '500px'
  });
}
```

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.parent--200 {
  width: 200px;
}
.parent img{
  max-width:100%;
  width: auto;
  display:block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent parent--200">
  <img src='http://placeimg.com/400/480/any'/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent">
  <img src='http://placeimg.com/400/480/any'/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent parent--200">
  <img src='http://placeimg.com/800/800/any'/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent">
  <img src='http://placeimg.com/800/800/any'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.parent img{
  max-width:500px;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Изображение может быть любой ширины. Для чего здесь медиа-запросы?

Comment: исправила, так как вы просите, но тогда это будет не адаптивный вариант

Comment: У вас сейчас картинка фиксированной ширины. Если ширина родителя меньше ширины изображения, то изображение должно быть 100% ширины родителя. Шри изменении ширины родителя изменяется ширина картинки.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое свойство `object-fit: scale-down;`

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_20254e252d91_128.png" alt="photo">
<img src="http://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201411/26/1334081/57542_trava_priroda_doroga_leto_1920x1200_wwwgdefonru.jpg" alt="photo">
```

Comment: Но место своё жрёт...

Comment: Есть такое дело, но в условии об этом не сказано

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить `max-width` в реальную ширину картинки с помощью js.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div img').forEach(function(img) {
    getImageRealSize(img.src)
      .then(size => img.style.maxWidth = size.width+'px');
  });
}

function getImageRealSize(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  return new Promise(ok => {
    img.onload = function() {
      ok({
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height
      });
    };
    img.src = src;
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/800/600'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

а что если ограничивать не картинку, а родителя?

вот пример для 200px

```
div { width: 200px; }
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vm6Lkppe/

Comment: В вопросе четко написано, что нужно. Родитель имеет ширину 100%.

Comment: Где в вопросе написано, что родитель имеет ширину 100%?

Comment: Если родителю не задана ширина, то она по умолчанию - 100%